# .htaccess Adding trail slashes

Tags: php, .htaccess

I got this code from somewhere.. and what it basically does is remove the .php extension

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule    ^Start/?$    index.php    [NC,L]    
RewriteRule    ^Info/?$    info.php    [NC,L]   
RewriteRule    ^Gallery/?$    gallery.php    [NC,L]
```

it does it work good, but because of some SEO stuff,, i need to add automatic traling slash at the end..

Now it is sitename.com/Start
But it has to rewrite itself to sitename.com/start/

Any solutions??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should handle this with a `301` redirect, placing it above the rules that you already have defined:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.) 
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
```

It is also worthwhile to remove the optional trailing slash flag in the rules that you've already defined, so your resulting `.htaccess` file will look something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.) 
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L] 

RewriteRule ^Start/$    index.php   [NC,L]    
RewriteRule ^Info/$     info.php    [NC,L]   
RewriteRule ^Gallery/$  gallery.php [NC,L]
```

In order to avoid the first condition rewriting valid files too, you should add in another condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

Finally, your `.htaccess` should look like:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.) 
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L] 

RewriteRule ^Start/$    index.php   [NC,L]    
RewriteRule ^Info/$     info.php    [NC,L]   
RewriteRule ^Gallery/$  gallery.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: A redirect is the way to do it, but the fact this is needed at all is questionable.  What seo requirements could there be? is GA listening in on a URL with that slash?

Comment: Hmm very strange.. @BenM .. The code seems to work.. i now get a / on everyone thats great.. But now the problem is it shows my pages without .css ??

Comment: Hmm @BenM i think there is still something missing in there.. When i click on a div button to go to domainname.com/info/ it redirects me to domainname.com/start/info/

Comment: No, that's not a fault of the rewrite. How are you linking the button? Remember you need to add **relative** links, so it would be better to link to `/info/` (with leading slash), rather than `info` (without it).

Comment: Haha okay, That works fine now thnx @BenM , But it would still not load the .CSS file i don't get it..

Comment: Again, links to the CSS must be relative. Prepend the `link` with a slash and see if that helps.

Comment: OK ! Works great now! You the man @BenM , Thnx this was very helpfull!